# select all "groups/partitions" where parameter is found

Tags: sql, db2

Without going into too much detail - I need to create groups (grouped on a specific field) of data and then display all GROUPS of records that contain a parameter.  I need all records in a GROUP even if some do not match the parameter.  Any GROUPS where no records contain the parameter would be suppressed.

I'm working with db2 and I just need help with the basic syntax.  I'm thinking a PARTITION_BY used within a subquery might be the correct approach.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you could upload some sample data and desired output.

Comment: I work with sensitive data, otherwise I'd happily oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it answer the question ?

```
with table1 (group_column, expression, other_column) as (
  values
  ('group1', 'false', 'First in G1'),
  ('group1', 'false', 'Second in G1'),
  ('group2', 'false', 'First in G2'),
  ('group2', 'true', 'Second in G2'),
  ('group3', 'true', 'Full G3')
)
select
  table1.group_column, expression, other_column 
from table1
  inner join
  (
    select
      distinct group_column
    from table1
    where expression = 'true'
  ) as groups on table1.group_column = groups.group_column
```

| GROUP_COLUMN | EXPRESSION | OTHER_COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group2 | false | First in G2 |
| group2 | true | Second in G2 |
| group3 | true | Full G3 |

Comment: This might work, thank you.  I do not have time today to work on this project, but I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: I am working with this today and I'm getting a "AMBIGUOUS" error on using(group_column) .  If I try to reference it another way using(table1.group_column) I get a syntax error.

Comment: @JobbieDaddy Just made an edit, changed join expression, `expression` column type, and select clause. Which DB2 do you use (LUW/Cloud/Zos/As400/Iseries/Ibmi) and version ?

Comment: This worked great!  I was able to basically add it to the end of my monstrosity of a query, add in my parameter and it works as expected.  Thank you!